# Deploy Windows XP Hyper-V VM to Azure?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, hyper-v, azure

Is it now possible to deploy a Windows XP VM to Azure?

I know before everything had to be based on Windows Server, but now, since you can also deploy Linux, shouldn't it be possible to deploy XP too? I've tried it, the VM got the status "Running" but it didn't look like it was actually online.

I've installed TeamViewer that would normally start automatically, but couldn't connect.

Answer (score 0):

It actually works. But make sure you have it running on Hyper-V first.